# преобразование map Scala в Java

Tags: java, map, scala

есть такой метод на scala:

```
override def visitObject(context: ObjectContext): Object = {
        (Option(context.fullNameField()).map(this.visitFullNameField) orElse
          Option(context.idField()).map(this.visitIDField))
          .get
      }
```

полностью ли соответствует этот java-метод тому, что написано выше?

```
@Override
public Object visitObject(ObjectContext context) {
    if (context.fullNameField != null) {
        return (this.visitFullNameField(context.fullNameField))
    } else {
        return (this.visitIDField(context.idField))
    }
}
```

и как на java будет выглядеть вот такой метод:

```
override def visitObject(context: ObjectContext): Object = {
    Object (context.arrayCtx().asScala.map(this.visitArrayCtx): _*)
  }
```

когда контекст представляет из себя коллекцию ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. В Scala-варианте ты добавил еще проверку `context.idField()` на `null`. В остальном - эквивалентно.